# PHP CuRL - Empty response due to SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, php-curl

I'm going to ask a question that's already been asked a lot, but I can't find a solution that works on my server.

I make a call with PHP on an API where I am correctly identified. I get the famous error 52 (Empty reply from server).

I tried all the parameters indicated on Stack but nothing works. I'm on a Ngnix server with an SSL Lets encrypt.

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxx/route/rest?=",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 100,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "app_key=" . env('APP_KEY')
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

If you could help me, I would be very grateful.
**Have a nice day**
Eliott

Comment: Why do you think SSL is the problem? You have an `http:` URL, not `https:`, so you're not using SSL.

Comment: If your server redirects HTTP to HTTPS, you need `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`

Comment: Hi @Barmar I think is SSL or https because on my local server, i'ts work well (on localhost)

Comment: And on postman, it's work well

Comment: Postman probably follows redirects by default, `curl` doesn't. You need that option.

Comment: Or just use the correct HTTPS URL.

Comment: Try to use `var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));` after executing `curl_exec($curl);` to see the detail of result. It should help you to debug the problem.